# Confused about taking file name from command line and stuff to it C++

Tags: c++, file-io

My problem is that I cant get the getting the filename from the command line from the user, then using that filename to write the median, mode, and average. Im new to c++ so any tips or code fix would be great, and if you guys see anything else wrong please let me know, this is what I have, Im 99% done with it its just this filewriting thats giving me problems. Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fsteam>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

double Median(int [], int);
double Average(int [], int);
double Mode(int [], int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  ofstream outFile;
  string filename = argv[1];

  outputFile.open(filename.c_str());

  if(!outFile)
  {
    cerr << "Error with the file.";
  }
  else
  {
    continue;
  }


  int *array;
  int array_size;
  cout << "How many students were surveyed? " << endl;
  cin >> array_size;

  if(array_size < 1)
  {
    cout << "Number of students surveyed must be greater than 1." << endl;
    return(1);
  }
  else
  {
    array = new int [array_size];
  }


  cout << "Enter the number of movies each studen saw." << endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
  {
      cout << "Student " << i+1 << ": " << endl;
      cin >> array[i];
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
  {
    for(int j = i+1; j < array_size-1; j++)
    {
      if(array[i] > array[j])
      {
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }

  double median = Median(array, array_size);
  double average = Average(array, array_size);
  double mode = Mode(array, array_size);
  outFile << "Median: " << median << endl;
  outFile << "Average: "<< average << endl;
  outFile << "Mode: " << mode << endl;

 return 0;
}

double Median(int arr[], int size)
{
  double middle;
  if(size%2 == 0)
    middle = (arr[size/2] + arr[size/2-1])/2;
  else
    middle = arr[size/2];
  return middle;
}
double Average(int arr[], int size)
{
  double ave = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
    ave += arr[i];
  ave = ave/size;
  return ave;
}
double Mode(int arr[], int size)
{
  int count, mode = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    count = 1;
    while(arr[i] == arr[i+1])
    {
      count++;
      i++;
    }
    if(count > mode)
      mode = arr[i];
    if(count > 1)
    i--;
  }
  return mode;
}
```

Comment: What command line arguments are you giving it? When you set a breakpoint at the `outputFile.open` line, what is the value of `argv[1]`? In other words, what specific error are you getting?

Comment: g++ -c movie_stats.cpp
movie_stats.cpp:2:18: fatal error: fsteam: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [movie_stats.o] Error 1 ////this is the error im getting

Comment: Oh, so you're getting compile time errors? The description sounded like you were having run time difficulties. As user3210680 noted in his answer, you misspelled `fstream`.

Comment: yea he was correct, but thank you too chris for taking your time to help

Comment: I tried too. please reference my patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely see something about this in the compiler, but I'll let you know anyways `#include <fsteam>` is `<fstream>`

I'm confused as to why you chose to put this

```
      else
  {
    continue;
  }
```

instead of nothing, since `continue;` just jumps to the end of the current iteration, which doesn't seem necessary here.

The rest of it seems fine. It's formatted to be easily read. If you have any errors post-testing, let me know.

EDIT: Sorry, I can't add comments yet, but in response to your comment, it's likely because of what I noted about `<fstream>` above. It's just a typo.

Comment: WOW!!!, I cant believe it was that, so i was doing it right just misspelled <fstream> I cant believe i didnt see that. Thank you so much, and I deleted that else statement with the continue, what else can i put in there to to check for errors?

Comment: @xiaodongjie got you covered. I didn't notice `outputFile` being any different, but she did. You had a typo there. I think that's it.

Comment: I'm surprised the compiler didn't have an error when it was unable to find "fsteam" in the include path. But the same applies to the continue. There is no do, while, or for in the scope. The compiler should have had an apoplexy.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with following patch.

```
--- orig.cpp    2014-05-17 12:39:37.000000000 +0800
+++ new.cpp 2014-05-17 12:38:28.000000000 +0800
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 #include <iostream>
-#include <fsteam>
+#include <fstream>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;
@@ -16,13 +16,13 @@

   outputFile.open(filename.c_str());

-  if(!outFile)
+  if(!outputFile)
   {
     cerr << "Error with the file.";
   }
   else
   {
-    continue;
+//    continue;
   }


@@ -64,9 +64,9 @@
   double median = Median(array, array_size);
   double average = Average(array, array_size);
   double mode = Mode(array, array_size);
-  outFile << "Median: " << median << endl;
-  outFile << "Average: "<< average << endl;
-  outFile << "Mode: " << mode << endl;
+  outputFile << "Median: " << median << endl;
+  outputFile << "Average: "<< average << endl;
+  outputFile << "Mode: " << mode << endl;

  return 0;
 }
```

I think that as following.

first, You type incorrectly with `fsteam` -> `fstream`.

second, you type incorrectly with `outFile` -> `outputFile`.

third, you must don't use `continue` without loop.

As result, I suggest you have more focus about typing error.

Comment: yea i wrote the part of it a couple days ago, and i forgot what i named the outputFile variable, but i figured those out after i was told that fstream was misspelled but thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Better to check the count command line arguments.

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    if(argc <2 )
    {
    cout << "Specify out file name as command line argument";
    return 0;

    }
        . . . . . 
        . . . . .

    }
```

for more details,

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html